# Show that the space of continuously differentiable functions is a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces

Show that the space of continuously differentiable functions $C^k(\Omega)$ is a Banach space
with
$\|f\|_{\infty,k}:=\sum_{j=0}^k \sup_{x \in \Omega} |d^j f(x)|$.

How would I show this? I'd need to show that $C^k(\Omega)$ is complete, but where would I start?

Comment: $\Omega$ should be compact right ?

Comment: Yes, it's compact. I figured out how to show that it is indeed a Banach space however I'm struggling to show the second part of my question.

Comment: By Weierstrass Theorem, every continuous $f:\Omega \to \mathbb R$, where $\Omega$ is compact, attains its maximum and minimum.

Comment: Would it be enough to simply say that? I don't see why this proves that $||f||_{\infty,k}$ is exactly what I wrote in my post?

Comment: The other thing is that the space $C(\Omega)$ of continuous real-valued functions, is a Banach space with the supremum norm, in particular it is complete.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this explanation.

Comment: Wait a minute, what is a $d^j$ or $d^a$ sa you wrote it in the definition of the norm ??? If that is a differentiation operator, how does it act where $\Omega$ is just any (compact)topological space ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134802/discussion-between-illuminatitruthseeker-and-physor).

Comment: @Physor I expect $d$ will be the diameter of $\Omega$.

Comment: @JackT This question is not clear to me, but I'll follow it for a while

Comment: @Physor - the problem concerns the space $C^k(\Omega)$ of functions on $\Omega$ all of whose $k$-order derivatives are continuous. Clearly $\Omega$ is not some arbitrary compact topological space, but a space for which differentiation is defined. Probably it is intended to be a domain in $\Bbb R^n$. But it could be in some TVS or a manifold instead.

Comment: Yeah, clear, but would one do anything concretely on this problem without knowing what that space is and how the derivative are defined ? how do we e.g. compute $d^j f (x)$, what is that, is it a vector, a linear map, a scalar and what is the norm of it, ... or what. I don't mean to be rude

Answer (score 1):

The key point is to show that "the derivative of the limit is the limit of the derivatives", namely, (for simplicity in one variable), showing that if $f_n\to f$ in the $C^1$ topology, then $f'_n\to f'$ in the $C^0$ topology.

By definition of the $C^1$ topology, if $f_n\to f$ then $f_n\to f$ in the $C^0$ topology, and $f'_n\to g$ for *some* continuous $g$. To show that $g=f'$ is essentially the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: But what is derivative of a function on an arbitrary compact topological space ? Just check the discussion

Comment: @Physor, there _is_ no general defn of derivative on topological spaces. More structure, such as smooth manifold, is needed for it to be sensible.

Comment: I know,........